# C# - Null error while nothing is null

Tags: c#, mysql, null

I'm currently coding a MySQL class in C#, but I'm keeping getting Null error.

```
object obj = this.Command.ExecuteScalar();
```

It says that is null, but this.Command is NOT null. And if ExecuteScalar() is null it will just append obj as null. My whole class is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace RushEmu.DB
{
public class DbClient : IDisposable
{
    public MySqlConnection Connection
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MySqlCommand Command
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DbClient(DbManager Manager)
    {
        Connection = new MySqlConnection(Manager.ConnectionString);
        Command = new MySqlCommand();
        Command.Connection = Connection;
    }

    public void AddParamWithValue(string key, object value)
    {
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, value);
    }

    public void Execute(string qry)
    {
        Command.CommandText = qry;
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Command.CommandText = null;
    }

    public T Return<T>(string qry)
    {
        Command.CommandText = qry;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(DataTable))
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            new MySqlDataAdapter(Command).Fill(data);

            Command.CommandText = null;

            return (T)(object)data;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DataRow))
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            new MySqlDataAdapter(Command).Fill(data);

            Command.CommandText = null;

            if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return (T)(object)data.Rows[0];
            }
            else
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(MySqlDataReader))
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
            Command.CommandText = null;
            return (T)(object)reader;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar());
            Command.CommandText = null;
            return (T)(object)i;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(uint))
        {
            uint i = Convert.ToUInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar());
            Command.CommandText = null;
            return (T)(object)i;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            object obj = this.Command.ExecuteScalar();
            string i = (string)obj;
            Command.CommandText = null;
            return (T)(object)i;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
        {
            bool i = Convert.ToBoolean(Command.ExecuteScalar());
            Command.CommandText = null;
            return (T)(object)i;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            DateTime i = Convert.ToDateTime(Command.ExecuteScalar());
            Command.CommandText = null;
            return (T)(object)i;
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It is a most awesome usage of generic method.

Comment: Could you show how do you call this class methods?

Comment: Please, provide us a stacktrace.

Comment: CommantText of the command is empty? Have you looked as the stack of the exception. Maybe its some internal of the command object that has a problem because it wasn't initalized correctly.

Comment: No, CommandText is not empty. 

02:02:20 [#] System.NullReferenceException: De objectverwijzing is niet op een e
xemplaar van een object ingesteld.
   bij MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   bij RushEmu.DB.DbClient.Return[T](String qry) in C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\Vi
sual Studio 2010\Projects\RushEmu\RushEmu\DB\DbClient.cs:regel 92
   bij RushEmu.RushEnvironment.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\
Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RushEmu\RushEmu\RushEnvironment.cs:regel 81

And the line is the same line as I said in my post.

Comment: From the stack trace in the above comment we can see that the exception arises (not until) inside the `ExecuteScalar()` method. So you are right `Command` is not null. Something inside the `MySqlCommand` code is null.

Comment: Don't mind, forgot to open the connection.

Comment: @The Coderz Nerd : Can you add that as an answer? Otherwise people will keep looking at your question thinking it's unanswered.